# Why is my DataGridView in VB.Net doubling in size every time I access the Access Database?

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access, datagridview, oledb

I have some basic code here that calls in an Access Database ("Houses") and that's about all. However, every time I click the button, the size of the DataGridView doubles. What I mean is that if the actual Access database has 5 rows, the DataGridView shows the correct database initially, but after each click of the button it goes up to 10 rows (they repeat), then 15, then 20 etc. Unfortunately I can't place this in the Form_Load area.

I tried placing "dt.rows.clear()" before "dgv.DataSource = dt", but it wipes everything. Also tried "DirectCast(Dgv.DataSource, DataTable).Rows.Clear()" and "Dgv.Datasource = Nothing"

```
Public Class frmHouses
Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable()
Dim connStr As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=Houses.accdb"
Dim sqlStr As String = "SELECT * FROM Property"

Private Sub btnRecord_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnRecord.Click

    Dim dataAdapter As OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sqlStr, connStr)

    dataAdapter.Fill(dt)
    dataAdapter.Dispose()

    dgv.DataSource = dt

End Sub
```

Thanks!

Comment: `dt` is a global variable and it keeps the data from the previous click (you are not deleting its contents before connecting to the DB), just write `dt = New DataTable()` before `dataAdapter.Fill(dt)`.

Comment: Thank you! That worked. I love this site

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Class frmHouses

Dim connStr As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=Houses.accdb"
Dim sqlStr As String = "SELECT * FROM Property"

Private Sub btnRecord_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnRecord.Click
    Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable()
    Dim dataAdapter As OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sqlStr, connStr)

    dataAdapter.Fill(dt)
    dataAdapter.Dispose()

    dgv.DataSource = dt

End Sub
```

OR you can

```
Public Class frmHouses
Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable()
Dim connStr As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=Houses.accdb"
Dim sqlStr As String = "SELECT * FROM Property"

Private Sub btnRecord_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnRecord.Click
    dt.clear()
    Dim dataAdapter As OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sqlStr, connStr)

    dataAdapter.Fill(dt)
    dataAdapter.Dispose()

    dgv.DataSource = dt

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Class frmHouses
Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable()
Dim connStr As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=Houses.accdb"
Dim sqlStr As String = "SELECT * FROM Property"

Private Sub btnRecord_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnRecord.Click
    Dim dataAdapter As OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sqlStr, connStr)
    dataAdapter.Fill(dt)
    dataAdapter.Dispose()
    IF dgv.Rows.Count > 0 Then
    dgv.Rows.Clear()
    End IF
    dgv.DataSource = dt
End Sub
```